# High Pass with nodes

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm attempting to recreate a photoshop technique I learned in a video with blender's node system. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoeZzxm5W88) I of course searched  google and haven't been able to recreate the technique correctly. It always seems off. I don't have a great understanding of nodes/photoshop so it might be a really simple task but I've been stuck on it a while so any help would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=high+pass

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.
When you check "transparency" the alpha needs to match the object.
This is setup using the realtime compositor 3D VIEWPORT in Blender 3.6
[image]
The "mix" node that goes out from the alpha, has a 0.5 value for the second slot color. This will tint the alpha to a 0.5 required value to do the pixel offset by difference.